# Django simple math captcha , how to pass custom string as argument?

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-simple-math-captcha plugin from here: https://github.com/alsoicode/django-simple-math-captcha

I have successfully configure it and it works. Practically this is my code:

```
from simplemathcaptcha.fields   import MathCaptchaField

class ContactForm(Form, FormMixin):
    captcha = MathCaptchaField()
```

By the official documentation if you wanna to change some default setting in mentioned captcha, you just need to pass it as argument. For example, I wanted to change default question string and in documentation says:

> Optionally, you can pass in the following arguments to the field to configure it.
>
> ....
>
> **question_tmpl**
>
> A string with format placeholders to use for the displayed question.
>
> Default value: "What is %(num1)i %(operator)s %(num2)i?"
>
> ...

I have tried to do in this way:

```
captcha = MathCaptchaField(question_tmpl="What is the result of %(num1)i %(operator)s %(num2)i?")
```

and after I added this change django gave me an error

```
**TypeError at /contact/**

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'question_tmpl'
```

What is a right way to pass following argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using both django-allauth and django-simple-math-captcha and need to internationalize:

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'your_app.forms.AllauthSignupForm'
```

forms.py

```
from simplemathcaptcha.fields import MathCaptchaField
from simplemathcaptcha.widgets import MathCaptchaWidget

class AllauthSignupForm(forms.Form):
    captcha=MathCaptchaField(widget=MathCaptchaWidget(question_tmpl=_('What is %(num1)i %(operator)s %(num2)i ? ')),
    error_messages = {'invalid': _('Please check your math and try again.'), 'invalid_number': _('Enter a whole number.')})

    def signup(self, request, user):
    """ Required, or else it throws <The custom signup form must implement a "signup" method>"""
    pass
```

signup.html

```
{{ form.captcha }}   {{ form.captcha.errors }}
```

Answer (score 3):

By reading [the code](https://github.com/alsoicode/django-simple-math-captcha/blob/master/simplemathcaptcha/widgets.py#L11), I believe the doc is incorrect. And currently, you need to use `MathCaptchaWidget`:

```
captcha = MathCaptchaField(widget=MathCaptchaWidget(
           question_tmpl="What is the result of %(num1)i %(operator)s %(num2)i?"))
```